# How do I get the edges of the Manhatten Voronoi texture?

Tags: texturing, node-editor

So I was trying to create a sci-fi building material for a building and I wanted to use the Voronoi texture. I found Manhattan to be the most suitable but I found out that I'm not able to make the edges a thing. The edges are only available for Euclidean when using "Distance to Edge". I didn't find any solution, any ideas on how to make it?

Answer (score 4):

You can output it to a ColorRamp to get this kind of effect :
[image]
Note that the interpolation is set to Constant, to get a clean sharp edge.

Instead of the ColorRamp, you can probably use some Math nodes for a more controllable effect.

Comment: Yeah I did come across that effect using the color ramp.  I wonder if they are considering something for Manhattan Voronoi and distance from the edge...